# SQL JOINING 5 tables due to a criteria

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 5 tables in MySQL, but i believe this is a SQL problem

**USERS**

[image]

**USER_INFO**

[image]

**USER_RIGHTS**

[image]

101 = read right

102 = write right

**GROUPS**

[image]

**POSTS**

[image]

Now i want to select for user 2 for example, all posts made by any user where user 2 has the read right 101 in that group

For example i have 3 post

post 1 posted in group 1
post 2 posted in group 1
post 3 posted in group 2
post 4 posted in group 1

and

```
WHERE user2 has 101 right in group 1 ==> SHOW post1 2 3
```

or

```
WHERE user2 has 101 right in group 2 ==> SHOW post2
```

or

```
WHERE user2 has 101 right in both group 1 and group 2 ==> SHOW post2
```

What i have so far is

```
SELECT * FROM posts
INNER
    JOIN user_info
    ON posts.posted_by = user_info.user_id  
INNER
    JOIN groups
    ON posts.posted_in = groups.group_id
INNER
    JOIN user_rights
    ON user_rights.user_id = user_info.user_id
WHERE user_rights.right = '101' AND user_info.user_id = ".$UserId." ORDER BY id DESC;
```

This piece of code returns me all posts 2 times.

Comment: Why don't you merge user, user_info and user_rights? As long as there aren't multiple rows for one userID in user_info and user_rights, that should make things a lot easier already. /edit: Also, change user_info.user_id to posts.user_id in the WHERE clause.

Comment: believe me, i have to leave that structure the way is it, because in the future i only want to extent user_info, and the PHP architecture will not like extending the whole table ...

Comment: Why not? Firstly, you don't have to select everything from the table, and secondly, why shouldn't PHP like it?

Comment: believe me, i really need to have more tables, i need that architecture, i will never struggle just to prove my point, i really need to let it that way

Comment: half of your joins are useless. im not sure how you get all of ur posts 2 times (assuming you have more users than user 1), but you certantly need to reduce to joins (event if it doesnt solve the problem, it will make ur query more readable at least)

Comment: @hugelgupf - Actually, `user_rights` has multiple values for the same `user_id`, at least, thats what the example shows, so why are you arguing about it?

Comment: You're right, @Lamak, I just noticed that. Besides my entire first comment is BS, so just disregard it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Im pretty much convinced this

```
select * from posts 
inner join 
(select group from user_rights where right = 101 and user_id = 1) as rights
on posts.posted_in = rights.group
```

would work in SQL server (dont have one here to check the syntax).

On one side im selected all the groupswhere user with id 1 has a read permssion

On the other i select the posts. 

All is left is the inner join between them.

Comment: it doesn't seem to work, i have sintax error LINK => aplicatii-iphone.ro/img/licenta.rar here is the whole MySQL database dump, it seems it doesn't work, i tried, or am i wrong?

Comment: I have no idea. you asked it as a general sql question, and as such (concept wise) my answer should work. I never used mysql so i wouldnt know...

Comment: no it isnt. Every sql engine provider has his own implementations, just like with ECMA script. the select works fine on sqlfiddle, once the (apparently saved words) group and right are replaced with anything else, both in the schema and the select.

Comment: this works for me: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5b289/1 it returns posts only from group 1 and 3, where user 1 has permission 101. Notice i changed column group to group_id and right to user_right, to make the engine graps it.

Comment: IT WORKS! and don't you have the "obsession" to put user_rights.user_id instad of pure user_id ? because i have this ... and second, are you sure this is the right way to do it? a select within a select? how about my 4 JOINS ?

Comment: Im not sure your option will work at all, it seems (from a first look) it will return only a part of the results. Even if it does, my way saves few not-needed selects and then all the operations required by the SQL engine to calculate the result of join operations. You are welcomed to check my version with different sets, and mark it as accepted as well :)

Comment: thank you very much for your help, it really helps me, but i have to understand it well, a copy paste solution is not what i need, i'm confused about "AS" witch i only used in alias, but now i see i use it in another select within a select ... wow! anyway, thank you very much!